# Storing JSON Dictionary Values into Variables

Tags: php, json, swift, dictionary

Using a PHP file, I echoed data from a MySQL database in the following format: `[{"longitude":"-122.031","latitude":"37.3323”}]`

In my Swift file, I use `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData()` to create a JSON dictionary that looks like the following

```
(

    {

        latitude = "37.3323";

        longitude = "-122.031";

    }

)
```

If I wanted to store the **individual dictionary values** inside variables, I believe the following snippet of Swift code would work

```
class Location: NSObject {
    var latitude: String?
    var longitude: String?
}

var locations = [Location]()

if let locationDictionary = jsonDictionary["coordinates"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let location = Location()

        location.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(locationDictionary)

        print(location.latitude, location.longitude)
}
```

The only problem I’m having is that I need my JSON dictionary to look like

```
(

    coordinates =  {

        latitude = "37.3323";

        longitude = "-122.031";

    }

)
```

but I don’t know what steps to take to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to make your JSON like this:

> [{"coordinates":{"longitude":"-122.031","latitude":"37.3323"}}]

which is an array of dictionaries, where each dictionary contains another one.

And here is your code adapted for the new format:

```
if let json = try? NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []), // your source may differ, I'm just using this line for my example
    content = json as? [[String:AnyObject]] { // the array of dictionaries
    for item in content {
        if let locationDictionary = item["coordinates"] as? [String: AnyObject] { // the dictionary inside the dictionary
            let location = Location()
            location.setValuesForKeysWithDictionary(locationDictionary)
            print(location.latitude, location.longitude)
        }
    }
}
```